# Tikz cspst switch doesn't have the arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Please let me know why I get a switch without an arrow:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}
\pgfsetlayers{myback,background,main}
\tikzset{mycolor/.style = {line width=1bp,color=#1}}
\tikzset{myfillcolor/.style = {draw,fill=#1}}
\tikzset{
  block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
    minimum width = 3em},
  sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, 
  input/.style    = {coordinate},
  output/.style   = {coordinate}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\draw
    node at (0,0)[right=-3.2mm]{}
    node [input, name=input1] {} 
    node at (1,0)(1){}
    node at (3,0)(2){}
    node [block, right of=input1] (sw1) { };
    \draw (1) to [cspst] (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`>=triangle 45` was removed and `[->]` was added to `\draw`